# Hibernate and Junit Test: rollback tests changes

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

Does someone knows a method to rollback a transactions carried out during a test ..

With Spring it would be easy ...

But I'm reviewing an application that does not use the framework ..

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do it manually on `@After` annotated method.

But I strongly encourage setting up an in memory db(such as HSQLDB) which could be generated from entities. That way, you'll have much faster tests and tests would not depend on each other - the purpose of unit tests.

Check this [link](http://vageeshhoskere.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/unit-test-with-junit-for-hibernate-using-hsqldb-in-memory/)